# Scaling vector graphics in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

This is a "how-to" question.

I have an android activity with 6 ImageView objects in a ConstraintLayout.  I would like them placed in a horizontal row, always using the full width of the screen.  For larger screens, instead of blank spaces between the ImageViews I would like the ImageViews to scale up, maintaining their aspect ratio. I am using vector resources for the content of the images.

How can this be done?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within `ConstraintLayout`, you can place your `ImageView` into a chain with

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
```

or

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
```

and make the width of each view `0dp` to expand each view horizontally to match its constraints. That will distribute each view across the width of the screen whether in portrait or landscape mode. (See [this discussion](https://medium.com/@nomanr/constraintlayout-chains-4f3b58ea15bb) of chains.)

Once that is done, specify `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for each `ImageView` that will make the vector image scale up to fill its view. (See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) and [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/correct-imageview-adjustviewbounds-with-adjustable-imageview/en)).

Below are two sample images and the XML used. (I used four images, but it will work for six as well.)

[image]

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cheticamp - Your answer was right on the money and your example well done and very helpful.